# RoR: Devise enum roles, redirect after sign in based on role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, devise

I have a user model with two roles as enums

```
enum role: [:'Standard', :'Admin']
```

I am trying to redirect based on the user role to relevant page after sign-in with Devise, I have used the recommended way of doing it on the docs.

In my sesssions controller...

```
  def create
    super
    sign_out :user
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(_resource)
    if resource.role == "Standard"
      redirect_to dashboards_path
    else
      redirect_to dashboards_admin_index_path
    end
  end
```

And in my controller...

```
before_action :authenticate_salesperson!
before_action :set_project, only: %i[show edit update destroy]
```

I get this error saying too many renders/redirects (highlights super in create method) when logging in and i'm wondering why?

```
Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return"
```

How to work around this? Ty.

Comment: I am wondering if `sign_out :user` really needed. Remove it and check if it helps.

Comment: I put that in to prevent two users types signed up at once (because I have another user model) which somehow happened to me.

Answer (score 1):

Would be nice if you paste the whole controllers, but it seems like the `after_sign_in_path_for` method gets called before each time you visit either page, which creates a loop and hence the error. You can easily verify this by logging some text in each of the if else methods to double check.

What you should do is to add this logic to the controller, which is the root path like so

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  before_action: :after_sign_in_path_for, only: :index

  private 

  def after_sign_in_path_for
     if current_user.standard?
       redirect_to dashboards_path
     else
       redirect_to dashboards_admin_index_path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I removed the redirect_to's in my sessions controller after sign-in method and it appears to work now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. This works after I removed the "redirect_to's" in the "after_sign_in" method in my sessions controller

```
   def after_sign_in_path_for(_resource)
     if current_salesperson.standard?
       dashboards_path
     elsif current_salesperson.admin?
       dashboards_admin_index_path
     end
   end
```

And in my user model...

```
  def admin?
    role == "Admin"
  end

  def standard?
    role == "Standard"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting too many times in the same action, this is why the message: "Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action."

Just return the path, delete redirect sentence! You only can redirect once in every action method!

Greetings